# How to access Magnolia v5.7 component property from Model java class

Tags: magnolia

- I have defined property in component dialog

[image]

- How I can access this value from execute() method in model class?
- Model class will request service at this url

Documentation discusses only how to access data within Model class, I need to pass url **into** Model class.

I can't send request from page by ajax, because service domain not exposed to extranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model class extends from `RenderingModelImpl`. Or at least it should :).
Because of that there's a constructor that get passed current component node in and it's exposed to you via `getNode()` method.
So assuming that when you click on `Save changes` in your dialog, the value gets persisted under `unsubscribeUrl` property, to access this value from `execute()` method:

```
public String execute() {
    // read unsubscribe url
    String unsubscribeUrl = this.getNode().getProperty("unsubscribeUrl").getString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ftl you can call the model with an argument:

```
${model.myMethod(content.unsubscribe_url)}
```

In your model you can use the argument to do what you need

```
 public class myMethod(String url) {
     do something ....
 }
```

Comment: my Unsubscribe page doesn't have FTL. It has been entirely composed in Author console page app. I will consider doing this page from scratch as FTL if nothing comes out.

Comment: Any suggestion how to convert or export already designed page to FTL template?

Comment: In Model class constructor I receive content argument `public UnsubscribeModel(Node content, RD definition, RenderingModel<?> parent) {
  super(content, definition, parent);
 }` can I access value of `unsubscribeUrl` through this `content` node?

Comment: I create component with FTL and model class; Define property unsubscribeUrl; add setUnsubscribe(url) in Model; place in FTL `${model.setUnsubscribeUrl(content.unsubscribeUrl)}` ; This method was NOT called.

Comment: What do you mean it was entirely composed in Author console page app?
If you create a page you choose a template, this template mus exist as an ftl file that includes the header, footer and code to render the components. Pages without a templates are non visible pages that return json for example. But all normal pages should have an ftl file.

Comment: As for your Java question, I do not know. I created a class to access a database and call it with parameters from the template. This is what I wanted to share.

Comment: Thank you Patriot for keep following this post. 1) I was referring to component inside page pointed as "page display after submit form" 2) call to Model class function from FTL happen only when I open page in design mode and after model.excute() method, NOT before. If I open page in browser model.setUnsubscribeUrl(content.unsubscribeUrl) not called at all.

Comment: PS. Because of time difference in our locations, my replies may not reflect current changes I did in experimental development.